Are total curvature and the unknoting number of closed orbits of algebraic vector fields bounded uniformly by the degree of vector field?
I  am interested in this  question since 1999 when I heared the  definition of  a knot and I read the  definition of unknoting and the  total  curvature  of  a  knot.

To  what  extent can closed orbits of  an  arbitrary  algebraic  vector field  of  degree $n$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$  have  complicated knot  structure?  More  precisely  are there uniform upper bound  $K(n)$  for  the  total  curvature and unknoting number of a  closed orbit of  a  polynomial  vector  field
$X=P_n(x,y,z)\partial_x+Q_n(x,y,z)\partial_y+R_n(x,y,z)\partial_z$  where $P_n,Q_n,R_n$  are arbitrary polynomials  of  degree $n$

