A polynomial vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$ which has a knot periodic orbit
Is there a  polynomial  vector  field
$$P(x,y,z)\partial_x+Q(x,y,z)\partial_y+R(x,y,z)\partial_z$$
which has  a closed orbit $K$ such that $K$ is  a non trivial knot?

my first candidate would be a torus knot. I am not sure right now, whether the description of a torus knot given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus_knot translates to polynominial functions $P,Q,R$ as requested.

@HenrikRüping  Thank you for this  comment. But I think that a  homemorphic  copy of  a  torus knot has a simple  parametrization whose tangent field is a linear vector field on $\mathbb{R}^4$. But my question is  about algebraic  vector  field in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

A motivation for this question is the following https://mathoverflow.net/questions/477495/are-total-curvature-and-the-unknoting-number-of-closed-orbits-of-algebraic-vecto

@HenrikRüping  Your idea was perfect please see the  answer  by  David  Speyer

@HenrikRüping  Since you talked about the torus knot  this remind me of the  following  questionwhich  arose me  one week ago: Can we perturbe  a torus knot  such that the  perturbed knot  would be  included in a (nearby) leaf of the Reeb  foliation? My  apology  for  asking this  extra  question here

Maybe one should ask whether every knot occurs in this way.

@YCor  Yes  that is  an interesting  question. This remind  me  of  my past (MO or  non MO?) as follows:  is every  closed analytic  curve a limit cycle of an algebraic  vector  field. If I am not  mistaken I asked this  question in MO

@YCor  And  I  guess the  answer was  negative  by  some  counting(countable-non countable) argument. I think Loic Teyssier  answer to my  question. any  way your  question is very interesting.  Thanks  about that

@YCor and the same point you mentiined but for linki

@YCor My answer shows they do.

@PierrePC   To be  honnest after  the comment of Yves I thought that perhaps  your  answer  do. But I realized that you perturbe  the  initial  system. So a knot type  can be realized by an  algebraic  system  not  the  original knot. Agree?

Yes, any knot type can be realized by my answer; that is what I meant by "every knot". My argument does not tell you anything about the actual knot. As I was saying somewhere else, would you mind asking any additional questions in a separate post, or in the chat?

For the Lorenz equations (which are polynomial), this was studied at least as far back as a 1983 paper in "Topology" by Birman and Williams -- MR0682059 if you have MathSciNet. The title is "Knotted periodic orbits in dynamical systems"; they prove, among other things, that the Lorenz flow has knots with arbitrarily high genus, and contains all torus knots.
There is also a 1997 volume of Lecture Notes in Mathematics entitled "Knots and Links in Three-Dimensional Flows", by R. Ghrist, P. Holmes, and M. Sullivan.
Both of these are referred to in the written version of the 2006 ICM address by Étienne Ghys, entitled "Knots and Dynamics", which is MR2334193 on MathSciNet if you have access, and is also posted on his website. There was a question on MSE some time back about a link to the video of his ICM talk, which may be of interest, and there is a nice website with many pictures by Ghys and Jos Leys that describes some of these ideas.

Thank you very much Vaughn for your very interesting answer

Here is an answer with many details to fill in. It will get you any knot.
Consider the closed solid torus $\mathbb D^2\times\mathbb S^1\subset\mathbb C^2$, and define on it the vector field $X:(x,u)\mapsto(-x,iu)$ (it goes along the torus, and is pushed to the center).
For any choice of (smooth) knot in any 3-dimensional manifold $M$, you can send the above torus to a neighborhood of it so that it winds in the same way. This induces a vector field on some neighborhood of your knot.
I claim that any field on $M$ whose restriction is close enough to the induced field will admit a closed orbit that flows once along the torus, hence is homotopic to the initial knot within the neighborhood. Indeed, provided the new vector field is still

transverse to the discs $\mathbb D^2\times\{\theta\}$ and
transverse to the boundary $\mathbb S^1\times\mathbb S^1$,

then there exists a well-defined Poincaré return map $f:\mathbb D^1\to\mathbb D^2$, it is continuous, and it sends the disc to a smaller disc. This means that, say by Brouwer's theorem, that $f$ has a fixed point, whose orbit must flow once along the torus by definition of the return map.
Now for your case, take any knot in $\mathbb R^3$, send the torus as described, and approximate the vector field to a high precision in this compact set by Stone–Weierstrass.

Thank  you very  much  for  your  answer. the  concept of torus knot   remind me of the  following  questionwhich  arose me  one week ago: Can we perturbe  a torus knot  such that the  perturbed knot  would be  included in a (nearby) leaf of the Reeb  foliation? My  apology  for  asking this  extra  question here

I am not sure what you are asking. (1) There are tori and knots in my answer, but no torus knots. (2) As far as I understand, the leaves of the Reeb foliation are topologically planes (except of course for the initial torus), so any injective image of a circle with values in a fixed leaf must be homotopic, within the leaf, to arbitrarily small circles; it can never be a (non-trivial) knot.

Yes  You  are  right. You  did not  consider  torus  knot and  I  did not say that "The  concept of  torus knot in your answer'. But the nearby leaves are not embedded  plane they are somewhat spiraling around the torus

Any way I asked the same question from the  other answerer and  commenter in this  post and  I  did  apologized (you and them) already  for  thiis  extra  question.

They are still injectively immersed planes, and that's enough. The spiraling does not matter. From an injective immersion $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$, you get a "knot" in $\mathbb R^2$ in the preimage, so you can contract it to a very small circle in $\mathbb R^2$. The image of the homotopy is a homotopy of the image, hence an isotopy, and the final result is a tiny circle in $\mathbb R^3$ that is just barely deformed, and it is a topological unknot.

Yes  I  see thanks

I  thiion  " it winds in the same way." need to be  clarified. I  understand  you pick  a  vector  field  with a  hyperbolic  attractor  which is  unknotted so after perturbation the  closed orbit  survives. Ok  What is the perturbation? The  solid  torus merely  contains  the  knot and its  center is  an unknoted periodic orbit. so I  do not see how  does your answer solves my question?

I don't understand the details of your questions, but let me try to answer anyway. The initial torus is abstract, but its image in $\mathbb R^3$ is knotted; its "center", i.e. the image of ${0}\times\mathbb S^1$, is knotted in the same way. Now for the new, polynomial vector field, the center is not an orbit anymore. However, my argument is that there still exists a closed orbit of that winds along the torus. This means that in the abstract torus, the orbit is homotopic to the central curve, but in $\mathbb R^3$ it is knotted the same way the torus is.

yes I see so let me think more about that

Now  i  completely  understand  what  you  say: a  tubular neighborhood of  a  knot  is modeled in an  abstract  solid  torus whose  center is  a hyperbolic  periodic  attractor so it  survives with algebraic  approximation. In fact in  your  argument you reconstruct the  structural stability of  hyperbolic  attractors. (They  survive with small perturbation). BTW is it obvious  that  a tubular  neighborhood of  every  kknot is diffeomorphic  to the  solid  tori?My  guess is yes because they  have trivial normal bundle?

This  is  an excuse to search  for  2  diffeomorphic submanifolds  of  $R^n$ with  non diffeomorphic  tubular  neighborhood? Any  way I  appreciate  your  beautiful idea

(1) Yes, tubular neighborhoods are always diffeomorphic to the normal bundle, and normal bundles of knots are trivial. (2) From this answer we learn that there are two embedded spheres $\mathbb S^{11}$ in $\mathbb R^{17}$ with different normal bundle. Would you mind asking any additional questions in a separate post, or in the chat?

Over at math.SE, I give two polynomials $F(x,y,z)$, $G(x,y,z)$, whose common zero locus is the trefoil knot, and which are smooth and transverse there. Therefore, $(\nabla F) \times (\nabla G)$ is a vector field tangent to the knot.

I think you should be able to get a shorter answer as follows. Take the sphere $S$ given by $x_1^2+y_1^2+x_2^2+y_2^2=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$. The vector field
$$p(-y_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+x_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial y_1})+q(-y_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}+x_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y_2})$$
is tangent to $S$, and its flow lines are of the form
$$(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2) = (r_1 \cos(p t), r_1 \sin(p t), r_2 \cos(q t), r_2 \sin(q t))$$
which is a $(p,q)$ torus knot in $S$.
To give an even more extreme example, if we use
$$(x_1^2+y_1^2)(-y_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+x_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial y_1})+(x_2^2+y_2^2)(-y_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}+x_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y_2})$$
then we should be able to get all the torus knots to occur in the same vector field: We'll have $T(p_1, p_2)$ on the torus $x_1^2+y_1^2 = \tfrac{p_1}{p_1+p_2}$, $x_2^2+y_2^2 = \tfrac{p_2}{p_1+p_2}$.
Now make a stereographic change of coordinates to get a vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$ rather than $S^2$. That will give you a vector field with rational functions as coefficients, and clearing out the denominators will just change the speed of the flow.
But I don't feel up to doing that computation right now, so I'll leave the details to you.

Thank  you  very  much  and  +1  for  your  perfect  answer which  perhaps? (I think)  is  a  negative  answer to the  linked  question. So the  Torus  knot idea of   @HenrikRuping  was a  very good idea

The  4 dim.  vector  field  is  just the  vector  field we discussed with  Henrik in the  comments.  I  did not  pay  attention that not  only torus but also 3  sphere is  invariant under the  linear vector  field.

Since you talked about the p-q ( torus) knot  this remind me of the  following  questionwhich  arose me  one week ago: Can we perturbe  a torus knot  such that the  perturbed knot  would be  included in a (nearby) leaf of the Reeb  foliation? My  apology  for  asking this  extra question  here
